# PHP Variable needed for Ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a static function call `Token::generate();` that is needed when submitting forms.

As you can see the variable `$token` that is using my method to create my token.
Then you see the variable `$hidden` that is add the var to the form.

The problem is that if the user fails log in then the form will clear so they can enter there information with the errors that were created in the last attempt.

If the user attempts to try again with that token, it will not work because token has already been used.

Should I just create a php file that will just generate a token? Then I could use ajax to make a get request to obtain the token?

Would there be a better way?

```
if ($user->isLoggedin()) {
            echo '<span class="profile-link"><a class="titles red-links" href="/' . $user->data()->username . '">' . $user->data()->username . '</a></span>';
        } else {
            $token = Token::generate();
            $hidden = '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' . $token . '">';
            ?><script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                document.body.style.paddingTop="3px";
                $('a[href^="#fallr-"]').click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(7);
                    methods[id].apply(this,[this]);
                    return false;
                });
                var methods = {  
                    login : function(){
                        var login = function(){
                            var username = $(this).children('form').children('input[type="text"]').val();
                            var password = $(this).children('form').children('input[type="password"]').val();
                            var remember = $(this).children('form').children('input[name="remember"]').val();
                            var token = $(this).children('form').children('input[name="token"]').val();
                            if(username.length < 1 || password.length < 1 || token.length < 1){
                                alert('Invalid!\nPlease fill all required forms');
                                console.log(token)
                            } else {
                                var data = {
                                    username: username,
                                    password: password,
                                    remember: remember,
                                    token: token,
                                }
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "login.php",
                                    data: data,
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(data){
                                        console.log('here');
                                        if(data === 'login_success') {
                                            window.location.href = '/members/';
                                        } else {
                                            $('#error').append(data);
                                            $('form#login')[0].reset();
                                            $('form#login').children('input[name=username]').on('click', function() {
                                                $('#error').html('');
                                            });
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        alert(textStatus);
                                        alert(errorThrown);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }                        
                        $.fallr.show({
                            icon        : 'secure',
                            width       : '400px',
                            content     : '<h4 class="titles">Login</h4>'
                                        + '<span id="error"></span>'
                                        + '<form id="login">'
                                        +     '<input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text"/'+'>'
                                        +     '<input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password"/'+'>'
                                        +     '<input type="checkbox" name="remember" type="remember"/'+'> Remember Me'
                                        +     '<?php echo $hidden; ?>'
                                        + '</form>',
                            buttons : {
                                button1 : {text: 'Submit', onclick: login},
                                button4 : {text: 'Cancel'}
                            }
                        });             
                    }
                };
            });
            </script>
            <a href="#" class="titles red-links">Register</a><span class="titles red">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span><a href="#fallr-login" class="titles red-links">Login</a>
```

Comment: Just have the `login.php` return a JSON response with a new token and text status. `{token:"…", status:"…"}` and use `JSON.parse(…)` on the client side to extract the data. This could potentially mean that you would modify your success function to expect a JSON response for consistency.

Comment: The login page needs the token to start. So the success message wouldn't work because I need the token before ajax sends the information. The token has to be sent with all the other data.

Comment: Why don't you just return a new token inside the AJAX's response to "refresh" the token of the form using javascript on the browser ?

Comment: You do have a token available. It's in the field you created in $hidden field, you would keep that.

Comment: @VitorLima How would I tell the ajax to refresh the token?

Comment: @AndrewMcCombs  Your PHP page that receive the ajax request isn't able to call the function that create a token?

Comment: @VitorLima Would that still be safe if the login page creates the token then send it to the modal on the homepage then I send the form with the token back to the login page.